# Meteor throws gyp error when I try to run npm install

Tags: meteor

When I run `npm install` on a meteor package I downloaded from coursera, I get the below error. Problem is I don't even understand what its talking about. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
=> A patch (Meteor 1.4.4.6) for your current release is available!
   Update this project now with 'meteor update --patch'.
Started MongoDB.
Errors prevented startup:

While loading package npm-bcrypt@0.8.6_3:
error: Command failed: C:\Users\Chidimma\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\bin\npm.cmd rebuild --update-binary
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Chidimma\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Users\\Chidimma\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2_3\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Chidimma\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2_3\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Chidimma\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-bcrypt\0.8.6_3\npm\node_modules\.temp-izvog2\node_modules\bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v4.6.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.17134
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\Chidimma\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2_3\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Chidimma\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2_3\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "rebuild" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node v4.6.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.6 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Chidimma\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-bcrypt\0.8.6_3\npm\node_modules\.temp-izvog2\npm-debug.log
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Chidimma\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Users\\Chidimma\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2_3\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Chidimma\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2_3\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Chidimma\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-bcrypt\0.8.6_3\npm\node_modules\.temp-izvog2\node_modules\bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v4.6.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.17134
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\Chidimma\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2_3\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Chidimma\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2_3\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "rebuild" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node v4.6.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.6 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Chidimma\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-bcrypt\0.8.6_3\npm\node_modules\.temp-izvog2\npm-debug.log


Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: Can you confirm, that you installed node-gyp and it's dev dependencies correctly according to [the windows installation guide](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows)?

Comment: Yes. I can confirm